# How to remove every character before "__" in a vector in [r]

Tags: r, string, vector

I have a vector

```
vec <- c("A__1","B__2")
```

For each element I want to remove everything before "__".

```
"A" "B"
```

I tried with sub

```
sub("__*", "", vec)
```

But it does not give me the expected output
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can specify either one or more characters of `_` with `+` followed by other characters (`.*`) - `.` represent any character

```
sub("_+.*", "", vec)
#[1] "A" "B"
```

Or specify the `.`

```
sub("__.*", "", vec)
#[1] "A" "B"
```